# Tense agreement in "What I was going for {was / is} ..."

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, tense-agreement

So, the smallest of things give rise to questions in my head.
And, I was wondering which of the following was the correct one. (or will it be, "which of the following is the correct one"?)

> What I was going for **was**

or

> What I was going for **is**

Should I keep the tenses in agreement, or could I use the tenses as I please (here as well, will it be "could I use the tenses as I pleased?"
I keep finding myself in doubt when trying construct sentences of this sort knowing that it wouldn't make a huge difference if I used either of the sentences.

Comment: *Smallest* is neither singular nor plural; it is an adjective.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh -- It is possible to have several things that are equally small.  They could be the smallest things being talked about.

Comment: Complete(d) sentences would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which if the following **is** the correct one?

Since you are currently looking for the answer to your posted question.

> 1) What I **was** going for **was**...
>   2) What I **am** going for **is**...
>   3) What I **was** going for **is**...
>   4) What I **am** going for **was**...

#1 you were trying to do something but have now stopped
#2 you are still trying to do something
#3 is not quite correct, but it's meaning can be understood to be the same as #2
#4 is incorrect and does not make sense

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the continuity of your action. If you were 'going for something' and you've already completed it, you should use *'was'*. If whatever you were 'going for' is still not over, you should use 'is', which means you may still "go for it" again.